# Need format the give string "18-MAY-92" using stringTokenizer and get int value of month

Tags: java, date, date-parsing

I am trying to format the date which is entered as a string using string tokenizer. Date format will be enter as

```
String str="18-AUG-92".
```

I am splitting it into

```
int ndate = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
int nmonth = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
int nyear = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
```

But during nmonth it's showing error that entered value "AUG" is in string.

I want to convert "AUG" to 08.

Anybody know?

Comment: Use DateFormatter instead of stringtokenizer

Comment: Use the built in date parsing facilities. Use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `parseCaseInsensitive` method to build a `DateTimeFormatter`. Parse into a `LocalDate`. This has methods for obtaining year, month and day of month as integers. The details are covered in many places. The linked questions may not be enough, use your search engine for the rest. Also `StringTokenizer` is legacy and not recmmended for new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are.

```
String datetime="18-Aug-92";
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(datetime, dateFormat);
System.out.println(date.getMonth().getValue());
```

Comment: Sure. have fixed the answer using DateTimeFormatter

Comment: Thanks. There are a couple of minor issues: month abbreviations are locale dependent, and the asker had `AUG` in all uppercase (which won’t work with your code). But you are basically showing the right classes to use, which is always helpful.

Comment: If you prefer, you may use the slightly briefer `date.getMonthValue()` for getting the 8 for August.